# Слово "всамделишний"

Tags: лексика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли литературным слово "всамделишний" в значении "настоящий", "реальный"?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово вполне литературное, оно имеет слегка иронический оттенок. Раньше оно было "детским", а потом стало очень даже взрослым, но шутливым.

> В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. Ч. 1-4 (1913-1932) Следственная же комиссия от Громовых завернула к Шапошникову, завернула попутно, «для проформы», потому что опытный следователь почти был убежден, кто **всамделишный преступник.**
>
> Дон Аминадо. Поезд на третьем пути (1954)   Занавес раздвигается и Никита Балиев, **всамделишный, живой**, в безукоризненной фрачной паре, с орхидеей в петлице, похолодевшей от волнения рукой дает знак Архангельскому...
>
> Юрий Трифонов. Утоление жажды (1959-1962) Она по-прежнему как будто не замечала, что имеет дело с мужчиной: Нагаев был для нее просто больной дяденька, **всамделишный пациент**, которого интересно лечить и выхаживать.
>
> Василий Аксенов. Апельсины из Марокко (1962)  ― огромный-преогромный, оранжевый-преоранжевый, самый что ни на есть настоящий, **всамделишный апельсин.**
>
> Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, (1968)  Он был **всамделишный хороший инженер,** только моторист-авиационник, в Марфино был завезён по ошибке, но прижился здесь и не рвался в другое место, справедливо считая, что вряд ли там будет лучше.
>
> Виктор Астафьев. Царь-рыба (1974)   Приезжие, не жалея добра, накачали Дамку и Командора спиртом, и те смекнули, что у одного из молодцов жена или теща работает в больнице, может, кто из них и фершал, и **всамделишный зубостав** ― золотом вся пасть забита, оскалится ― хоть жмурься, ― стало быть, стесняться нечего, успевай дармовщинкой пользоваться.

Имена приведенных авторов не позволяют никому усомниться в полном праве слова *всамделишный* участвовать в литературном процессе. Канцелярит и официоз - не литература, поэтому там его НЕТ.

Answer (score 6):

Странный этот Викисловарь. И то в нем не дописано, и это, а вот про просторечие, значит, точно решено... Кем, интересно? Где можно увидеть фамилию автора статьи? Как-то не очень доверяю словарю, куда любой может внести свою информацию. Но это так, эмоции. Просто частенько стали на этот словарь ссылаться.

Мне не нравится слово *всамделишный*, все-таки лучше сказать *настоящий*.
Если заглянем в более авторитетные словари, то и у Ушакова, и позднее у Ожегова слово *всамделишный* описывается как слово из детского языка. В словаре Ефремовой (2000 г.) есть помета — разговорное. То есть слово употреблять, конечно, можно, но не в официальных стилях.

Comment: Так значит, всё-таки не литературное? Тогда какая разница, разговорное, просторечное, "детское", т.е. окказиональное? Разговорное очень часто помечают как просторечие. В любом случае не норма.

Comment: Разговорный стиль - стиль литературного языка. Просторечие -вне нормы, за пределами литературного языка. Мы где-то это уже обсуждали.

Comment: Кстати, мне это слово тоже не нравится. Ощущение, что хотят подделаться под детскую речь, а выглядит это нарочито и неуклюже.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это просторечие:
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9